# Multivariate Integration with respect to Dirac Measure

Tags: measure-theory, dirac-delta, multiple-integral

Let $n\geq 2$, $A = \{x\in [0,1]^n|\exists t\in[0,1]: x = t\cdot (1,...,1)\}$, $B$ a Borel-measureable set and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ a measureable function.

I can not make sense of the following expression, i.e., rewrite it in another form or interpret it in any sense.

$$\int_B f(x) d\delta_A(x)$$

I thought about rewriting it as a curve integral since $A$ is a curve in $[0,1]^n$ but I am not sure how.

Comment: Which measure do you mean by $\delta_A$ for a general set $A$?

Comment: OP: The Dirac measure is usually one of the form $\delta_{x}(A) = 1_A(x)$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou $A$ is the straight line between the vector consisting only of zeros and the vector consisting only of ones. (first line of the post defines $A$ properly)

Comment: Yes... what $A$ is is perfectly clear. I was asking, given $C$ a Borel set, which measure do you mean by $\delta_C$?

Comment: Ok, sorry I missunderstood. $\delta_C(B) = \begin{cases} 1, & C\cap B \neq \emptyset \\ 0,& \text{else} \end{cases}$.
PS: This is not a measure...